# $\hat{e_\mu } \cdot \hat{e^\nu } \neq \delta _{\mu} ^{\nu}$? Tensor algebra question.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, tensors

Let $\hat{e_{\mu }}$ and $\hat{e^{\mu }}$ be the co- and contravariant basis vectors, respectively, for an arbitrary coordinate system Is it true that sometimes, $\hat{e_\mu } \cdot \hat{e^\nu } \neq \delta _{\mu} ^{\nu}$? I seem to have found a counterexample:

Try choosing covariant basis $\hat{e_0 }$=(1, 1) $\hat{e_1 }$=(1, 3).

Then $g_{\mu \nu} = \hat{e_\mu } \cdot \hat{e_\nu }=\pmatrix{2 & 4 \\ 4& 10}$

The contravariant basis is the solution to set of linear equations $g_{\mu \nu} \hat{e^\nu }=\hat{e_\mu }$. Wolfram gives

$\hat{e^0 }=$(-1/2, 3/2)

$\hat{e^1 }=$(-5/12, 13/2)

These do not satisfy the identity $\hat{e_\mu } \cdot \hat{e^\nu } = \delta _{\mu} ^{\nu}$.

Comment: Check that the "Wolfram" calculations are correct. I'm not sure that in your example $g_{\mu\nu}e^\nu=e_\mu$.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, the *definition* of the contravariant basis is that $e_\mu\cdot e^\nu = \delta_\mu^\nu$. If your computations don't satisfy that property, then there is an error in your computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of $e^0$ and $e^1$ is wrong.  The easiest way to solve is to find the matrix of the inverse metric tensor:

$$(g^{ij}) = \pmatrix{2 & 4 \\ 4 & 10}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(g_{ij})}\pmatrix{10 & -4 \\ -4 & 2} = \pmatrix{\frac 52 & -1 \\ -1 & \frac 12}$$

Then

$$(e^0)^T = g^{0j}e_j = \frac 52\pmatrix{1 \\ 1} -1\pmatrix{1 \\ 3} = \pmatrix{\frac 32 \\ -\frac12} \\ (e^1)^T = g^{1j}e_j = -1\pmatrix{1 \\ 1} +\frac 12\pmatrix{1 \\ 3} = \pmatrix{-\frac 12 \\ \frac12}$$

Now with the correct dual vectors we can test the biorthonormality condition:

$$e^0\cdot e_0 = \pmatrix{\frac 32 & -\frac 12}\pmatrix{1 \\ 1} = 1 \\ 
e^0 \cdot e_1 = \pmatrix{\frac 32 & -\frac 12}\pmatrix{1 \\ 3} = 0 \\
e^1\cdot e_0 = \pmatrix{-\frac 12 & \frac 12}\pmatrix{1 \\ 1} = 0 \\ 
e^1 \cdot e_1 = \pmatrix{-\frac 12 & \frac 12}\pmatrix{1 \\ 3} = 1$$

So we get $e^i\cdot e_j = {\delta^i}_j$ as expected.